# Nombre dinámico de variables dentro del bucle for

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo darle nombre dinámico a variables? Mi idea es la de tener un texto común (*texto*) seguido de la variable *i* que es a su vez el contador del bucle `for`.

```
for(let i=0; i<cantidadDiv;i++){
        var texto+i;
 }
```

Comment: Yo intenté lo mismo sin éxito, haz probado en usar un array donde almacenes ése grupo  de textos?

Comment: Podrías crear un array/arreglo. No es exactamente lo mismo, pero creo que te puede servir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No es posible asignar un nombre dinámico a una variable pero podemos hacerlo a propiedades de un objeto o bien usar matrices.

Ejemplo:

Asignación dinámica de propiedades a un objeto

```js
var variables = {};
var prefijo = 'texto';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  variables[prefijo + i] = 1;
}

for(var key in variables) {
  console.info(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay una forma de poder realizarlo pero no es recomendable ya que tu contexto serían solo variables globales, lo mejor sería hacerlo con arrays, sin embargo si aún deseas realizarlo debes usar:

- window["mi_prefijo" + (i).toString()]

Aquí un ejemplo de su uso:

```js
var mi_prefijo = 'prefix';

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  window[mi_prefijo + (i).toString()] = "Valor :" + (i).toString();
}
console.info(prefix0);
console.info(prefix1);
console.info(prefix2);
```

De esta manera tendrías variables con nombres dinámicos en tu contexto global.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Mi caso no es el mismo ya que quería nombrar los campos de un objeto, pero puede que os sirva mi ejemplo.
Yo tras probar con eval y windows sin resultados satisfactorios lo hice de esta manera para crear un objeto con los nombres de objeto enumerados.
Empecé haciendo un string con los nombres de los atributos y sus valores concatenados con &. Al acabar leí los valores con qs.parse.

```
import qs = require('qs'); //Estoy en Typescript
const valor = ['a','b','c'];
let stringvalue= '';
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const value= `valor${i}=${valor[i]}&`;
  stringvalue +=value;
}
const parsevalores= qs.parse(stringvalue);
console.log(JSON.stringify(parsevalores)) 
// {"valor0": "a"; "valor1":"b", "valor2":"c"}
```

En mi caso que tengo que devolver un objeto con 40 valores me fue muy útil. Espero que os sirve.
Es mi primer comentario de StackOverFLow, me haría ilusión algún like. jejeje. Gracias

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Esto no va de likes, aunque si de reputación. Las buenas preguntas y las buenas respuestas suelen ser premiadas con puntos. En este caso tu respuesta no contesta directamente a la pregunta. Si quieres conseguir "likes" (reputación) aprende primero cómo funciona este sitio. Léete [answer] y haz el [tour] para ello. Es probable que tu respuesta consiga puntos negativos en lugar de likes porque no esta siguiendo las normas del sitio, lo siento. Ve al [help] para más información. Puedes [edit] esta respuesta para responder bien a la pregunta y obtendras reputación.

Comment: Y por cierto, lo que escribiste es una respuesta, no un comentario :)